# Why is Stylesheet loaded when Contional Comment states it should be ignored?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, conditional-comments

I thought conditional comments would instruct the browser to ignore the content if the condition is not met?!

For example I want to only include a stylesheet if IE6 is the browser.  The following in located in the <HEAD> element of the page.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <link id="IE6StyleSheet" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/IE6.css" runat="server" />
<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/IE6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

How come IE7, IE8 and FF3 all load that stylesheet?!

NOTE: Changing the condition to [if lte IE 6] does not make any difference! :(

**MAJOR UPDATE**

I am a moron... I just noticed what I did wrong!
The example I'd given was slightly modified.  The path to the css file in under App_Themes! Of course the css was always loaded!!!

Comment: Are you sure the browser's actually loading the stylesheet, or are you assuming it is because it appears that way? The Firefox extension "Web Developer" has a command under the CSS menu called "View CSS" which will show you exactly what CSS the browser's loaded.

Comment: Very certain.
Using Web Developer in FireFox and the Dev Tool in IE8 I can dynamically disable the unwanted stylesheet by renaming the href.
Once I do that, IE8 and FF3 will then (funnily enough) ignore the stylesheet.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason why it shouldn't work. What doctype are you using? If you're using HTML (not XHTML) then self closing tags in the head aren't allowed. Does your page validate? Maybe lowercase the rel="stylesheet" and maybe add media="screen". If you put those same conditional statements in your body with text and not a stylesheet link, does that work?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
   <link id="IE6StyleSheet" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/IE6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This will only load the stylesheet for IE6 or lower versions. Here's a test script you can use, it will print out which version of IE you're using:

```
<p><!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 5]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer 5<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 5.0]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer 5.0<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 5.5]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer 5.5<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 5]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer 5 and up<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer lower than 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 5.5]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer lower or equal to 5.5<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer greater than 6<br />
<![endif]-->
</p>
```

You should not see any text in Firefox with this test code.

Comment: Unfortunately I had started with [if lte IE 6] and alas it also does not seem to work :(

Comment: Well what does the test script display in the browser?

Comment: http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/sidepages/example2.html
This page seems to work across my various browsers.
My question is why does my example above not work as expected

Comment: Oh and the example above correctly picks the browser version.
Even so...
<!--[if IE 6]>
 <link to stylesheet />
<![endif]-->
Still loads the stylesheet even if the browser is not IE6